# filtering from JSON output from curl using JQ

Tags: json, bash, curl, grep, jq

I'm trying to filter JSON file after I'm pulling it over Curl using JQ to have only Youtube video "id" printed with jq from Ubuntu shell, with no luck I need to have XEJLuJyxLDE after "id": only , pretty long list and I'm very new to linux and jq. Thanks for help. My command now is which doesn't work `curl -s 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?chart=mostPopular&locale=RU&maxResults=50&key=MY_API_HERE'  --header 'Accept: application/json' | jq ".id"`

```
 {
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "peo7sRMHdYZRkNABiJLj7xYZ0yo",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "DrIQh9Tabqk3iak4yonUCzJ3sTk",
      "id": "XEJLuJyxLDE"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "1pZQ8jDaavX6KnOyiFrHQQiZtHo",
      "id": "jO0luDEHesc"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "EJZ20jnqkqp7uTg5krUSK1SQE5s",
      "id": "ixl31324UxE"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "lGhY08GhkmvKFuDL-GWAc0ulq-4",
      "id": "EoxkdcQAZmQ"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "C8wQv894QbhKLeMUH0qR4cVVi7w",
      "id": "5nFpkCmb8e4"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "zgizGmrn5tpxE6x2Yb0Dbuays1E",
      "id": "tJvCygyNH4I"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "WnwrLmfpC1sLxZaQjQdF6LIKrck",
      "id": "racmy7Y9P4M"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "1Ye2Py_uXwlz25tukvCklZK9094",
      "id": "rDpC8RW6UIQ"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "_4CqgWptBzjcBVxNvgZj9Rc60Ws",
      "id": "ONAZ__UY8Ps"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "6Ft6e-4d96bOZz8ICutRq1V9UNs",
      "id": "RE8VF-mVkhw"
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "aQQyXts43CxaFmtTIHDgPAPIUnE",
      "id": "LVze229omm4"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
jq '.items[].id'
```

to retrieve all `id`s.